# what does const { variable } = require('xxx') mean?

Tags: javascript

I have been seeing below syntax, and trying to understand what's the different. i did some search on google, and didn't get answer.

```
const  plugin1 = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
const { plugin2 } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
```

are they same? could someone explain what's the different?

Comment: Look for the keyword `destructuring assignment`

Comment: that's all I want, thanks

Comment: Could also be related to export types, named and default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Simplistic Explanation

For people lazy to search, a simplistic explanation for destructuring assignment would be the following:

#### First scenario:

```
const  plugin1 = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
```

In the case above, the variable **plugin1** receive the *object* exported by the module `'awesome-typescript-loader'`.

Then, if you want to access its properties, you would have to call it like this:
`plugin1.propertyFoo`

#### Second scenario:

```
const { plugin2 } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
```

In this second case, what happens is that you already know that object exported by the module `'awesome-typescript-loader'` has a *property* called **plugin2**, but you **do not** want to import the whole *object* with **all** properties like on the **first** scenario.

So, you use this syntax `{ plugin2 }` that means basically that you created local variable **plugin2** that received only the *property* **plugin2** from the *object* that is being default exported by `'awesome-typescript-loader'`.

> This can be done on ***objects*** and ***arrays***.

#### Proper Definition

While the explanation above is true for many cases, it actually depends on the export type of what you are importing. So, it might not work for all cases. Please check the export documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for a more detailed and accurate information.

Also, for a proper definition and syntax, please look into [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

*I hope it helps!*

Comment: Slightly disagree. Module type and exports play an import role here.

Comment: @stealththeninja you are right, I tried to do a simplistic explanation. I will try to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ricky Mo, i got all i want

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)